# App No Longer Appearing In Email Share Menu to Import Files in iOS13

Tags: csv, import, ios13, info.plist, uti

My app needs to import files of type .csv from an email message. Prior to iOS 13, this was possible with the following additions to the info.plist file:

```
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>en</string>
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>My File Description</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.myCompany.myApp.csv</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>


<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.data</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>My File Description</string>
        <key>UTTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array/>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.myCompany.myApp.csv</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <string>csv</string>
            <key>public.mime-type</key>
            <string>application/myapp</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

The above info.plist elements registered my app such that it would appear in the share menu by pressing and holding an email attachment with a .csv file extension and then clicking on the share icon. At that point, a list of apps appear that can receive a .csv file. My app would appear in that list.

Now that iOS 13 is released, my app no longer appears in the share menu. It appears that others have a similar problem with importing files of type .gpx as documented in [developer forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/118932). Some have success, but others do not. Anybody have ideas on how to fix this problem?